# How to make words invisible in vim?

Tags: vim

In `vimwiki`, I can input a link like this:

```
[[link]]
```

When I put cursor on the line, `[[]]` is visible:

```
>[[http://www.google.com/]]<
```

When the cursor is moved away, `[[]]` is invisible:

```
>http://www.google.com/<
```

I notice this behavior in vim's help manual(`:help vim`): `*vim:*`(`*`s are invisible until I type <kbd>V</kbd>).

I cannot figure out how it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There isn't a topic in vim's help named just "keyword". What was that last thing?

Comment: Sorry, I changed it to `*vim:*`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a feature called "conceal" that was added in vim 7.3 (if I recall correctly).  For a simple example, try this.

Open a buffer and type three lines, the middle one being "foobarbaz".  Then enter the following ex commands:

```
set conceallevel=2
syntax match Todo /bar/ conceal
```

When your cursor is on the "foobarbaz" line, "bar" will be visible (and highlighted with the Todo highlight group if you have syntax highlighting on).  Once you move off the line, "bar" will disappear.

For more information see `:help conceal` and `:help conceallevel`.

Comment: Thanks. It's a good example. I can use `:set cocu=nvic` to hide `bar`.

Answer (score 5):

I think that hiding text can be a very helpful feature. Think about text folding or readability of links.

To hide text Vim 7.3 has introduced the "conceal" argument. Hiding text is a well defined Vim feature. It is not a dirty trick.
See

```
 :help :syn-conceal 
 :help 'conceallevel' 
 :help 'concealcursor'
```

Please note that conceal works only for syntax regions, not for matches.

I have no experience with conceal, so I can't provide an example out of the box.

Habi

Comment: Actually the conceal feature/argument works with keywords, matches and regions, however the concealends feature/argument only works with regions. See :h syn-arguments. (I'm using vim 8.0)